# How can I read a sql database backward

Tags: java, android, sql, database, eclipse

Hey Guys i have the question: how could I read a database from backward?
This is my method for reading the files:

```
Cursor cursor = myDb.getAllRows();

// Allow activity to manage lifetime of the cursor.
// DEPRECATED! Runs on the UI thread, OK for small/short queries.
startManagingCursor(cursor);

// Setup mapping from cursor to view fields:
String[] fromFieldNames = new String[] 
        {DBAdapter.KEY_KALO, DBAdapter.KEY_HYDRATE, DBAdapter.KEY_FAT, DBAdapter.KEY_PROTEIN ,DBAdapter.KEY_CAL};
int[] toViewIDs = new int[]
        {R.id.item_Kalorien,     R.id.item_KG_in_g,           R.id.item_F_in_g,     R.id.item_P_in_g,R.id.item_cal};

// Create adapter to may columns of the DB onto elemesnt in the UI.
SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter = 
        new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this,       // Context
                R.layout.item_tagebuch, // Row layout template
                cursor,                 // cursor (set of DB records to map)
                fromFieldNames,         // DB Column names
                toViewIDs               // View IDs to put information in
                );

// Set the adapter for the list view
ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
myList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);
```

Thank you for helping!:)

Comment: @Josef E. can you help me here?;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you had to change the konstructor of the query method to Desc